# Removing if statements when obtaining data from a table

Tags: matlab, if-statement, vectorization

I have the following table

```
       nc             a        b
0.9 <= nc           0.33    -0.45
0.5 <= nc < 0.9     0.95    -0.75
0.1 <= nc < 0.5     2.2     -0.97
       nc < 0.1     1.18    -0.77
```

which says that if the observed cloud cover if between the ranges shown then a and b are given as the values expressed in the table. I have written some code in matlab that should return these values given a vector of nc values:

```
nc = [0.1, 0.6, 0.5 ,0.2, 0.9];

a = nan(length(nc),1); % pre-allocate arrays
b = nan(length(nc),1);

for i = 1:length(nc)
    if nc(i) >= 0.9;
        ai = 0.33; 
        bi = -0.45;

    elseif nc(i) >= 0.5 & nc(i) < 0.9
        ai = 0.95; 
        bi = -0.75;

    elseif nc(i) >= 0.1 & nc(i) < 0.5
        ai = 2.2; 
        bi = -0.97;

    elseif nc(i) < 0.1
        ai = 1.18; 
        bi = -0.77;
    end

    a(i) = ai;
    b(i) = bi;
end
```

However, this seems like a very long way of doing this. In addition, this code will eventually be fed into a number of other functions and I'm a bit worried that having so many if statements and a for loop in general will slow things down. Could anyone comment on this or suggest a faster way (if useful) of doing this?

Comment: I think it should be `nc > 0.9` in the first line of the table?

Comment: As always; if you think something is slowing down your program then profile it, if its not then move on and don't worry

Comment: I think the a(i)=ai should be within the for

Comment: @Batsu It is within the for!

Answer (score 1):

loops in matlab are slow. You can improve your solution vectorizing the operation:

```
nc = [0.1, 0.6, 0.5 ,0.2, 0.9];

a =  2.2  * ones(length(nc),1); % by default in the 0.1-0.5 range
b = -0.97 * ones(length(nc),1);

f = find(nc >= 0.9);
a(f) = 0.33; b(f) = -0.45;

f = find(nc >= 0.5 & nc < 0.9);
a(f) = 0.95; b(f) = -0.75;

f = find(nc < 0.1);
a(f) = 1.18; b(f) = -0.77;
```

`find` will list the indices of the element that match the criteria, so you can modify the elements in the other vectors.

Comment: Since the advent of the JIT in Matlab your statement about loops is not universally true anymore. See [here](http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use logical indexing, by-passing the need to use the `find` function:

```
nc = [0.1, 0.6, 0.5 ,0.2, 0.9];
a =  2.2  * ones(length(nc),1); % by default in the 0.1-0.5 range
b = -0.97 * ones(length(nc),1);

a(nc >= 0.9) = 0.33; b(nc >= 0.9) = -0.45;
a(nc >= 0.5 & nc < 0.9) = 0.95; b(nc >= 0.5 & nc < 0.9) = -0.75;
a(nc < 0.1) = 1.18; b(nc < 0.1) = -0.77;
```